# Remove thanks star only from text, not from footnote

Tags: footnotes, titles

I use the `\thanks` command to include a first starred footnote with acknowledgments. The star should appear in the footnote, but there should be no star in the text (in this case right after the title). How can I remove the star only from the text and not from the footnote?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{This is my title\thanks{Here I thank people.}}
\maketitle
Here is a sentence.\footnote{Here is a footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd suppress the * in both places: in the footnote it would refer to nothing.

Comment: @egreg The style sheet requires a star in the footnote, but no mark in the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\maketitle` command in the `article` class redefines `\@makefnmark` in a group to print the marker in a zero width box, so as to preserve centering. Thus it's sufficient to define it to do nothing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\def\@makefnmark}
 {\def\@makefnmark{}\def\useless@macro}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\textheight=8cm % just to have a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\title{This is my title\thanks{Here I thank people.}}
\author{Sverre}

\maketitle

Here is a sentence.\footnote{Here is a footnote.}

\end{document}
```

The patch might be more detailed, removing all replacement text for `\@makefnmark`, that, with this patch, will become the replacement text for `\useless@macro`. But since it's in a group, the definition of `\useless@macro` will disappear as soon as the group ends.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There's a follow-up [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259304/use-same-formatting-for-thanks-footnote-as-the-one-created-by-footmisc).

Answer (score 4):

You can insert the footnote manually with the appropriate identifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\title{This is my title\footnotetext{\llap{\textsuperscript{*}}Here I thank people.}}
\maketitle
Here is a sentence.\footnote{Here is a footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - this will work for now (submission deadline is tonight). But for the record, I'd ideally want (for future use of the same style sheet) to define a command in my `.sty` file that will do this automatically, so that all I have to do is write the content of my acknowledgements in the `.tex` document.