# Reformat footnote mark for \thanks, but not for other footnotes

Tags: footnotes, titles, koma-script

I have a piece of complex code from [Use same formatting for \thanks footnote as the one created by footmisc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259304/use-same-formatting-for-thanks-footnote-as-the-one-created-by-footmisc) which makes sure that `\thanks` doesn't place a star in the the title, only in the footnote itself, and that the `\thanks` footnote has the same formatting as other footnotes in the text.

The other footnotes have a formatting created with KOMA script (I think I tweaked it from [Footnote marker in text should be superscript lining figure, but footnote marker in the footnote should be full size old style figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268373/footnote-marker-in-text-should-be-superscript-lining-figure-but-footnote-marker)).

Combined, it gives me this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}[%
        Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]
    \newfontfamily\footmarktextfont{CMU Serif}[% for footnote markers in the text
        Numbers = {Lining, Proportional}]

\usepackage{scrextend} % KOMA script for footnote marks hung left of the margin
    \newcommand*\footnotetextfrommargin{0em} % set distance for footnote text from the margin
    \deffootnote{\footnotetextfrommargin}% use distance from above
        {\parindent}% paragraph indent in footnotes
        {\thefootnotemark.\space} % footnote marks followed by a period and space in footnote
    \deffootnotemark{\footmarktextfont\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}} % use footmarktextfont for footnote markers in the text

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% 1. remove all redefinitions about footnotes done by \maketitle
%    and add \titletrue
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \titletrue
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
% 2. define a conditional
\newif\iftitle
% 3. redefine \@makefnmark to print nothing when \titletrue
\xpretocmd{\@makefnmark}{\iftitle\else}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@makefnmark}{\fi}{}{}
% 4. ensure \@makefntext has \titlefalse
%    that's justified by the fact that \@makefnmark
%    in \@makefntext is set in a box
\xpretocmd{\@makefntext}{\titlefalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{My paper on footnotes\thanks{\lipsum[4]}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

A\footnote{\lipsum[11]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The footnotes look like I want them, and the footnote mark for the numbered footnotes looks like I want. The problem is the footnote mark for the `\thanks` footnote.

(1) There shouldn't be a period after the star.

(2) The star should look exactly like the symbol `*`, which is high up on the line. In this case, however, it is a lowered star. This is either because the symbol used by the `\thanks` command is placed inside a math environment with `\ensuremath` (see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78223), but it doesn't say where this code snippet resides), or, as I've found in `latex.ltx` (line 2255), the symbol is defined as `\textasteriskcentered`. Either one will produce a lowered star (try `\ensuremath{*}*\textasteriskcentered` and see).

So my question is, how can I remove the period after the star and also have a normal non-lowered star in the `\thanks` footnote, without changing how other footnotes appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to patch/define the footnote in the command `\maketitle` only.

For example can you use your already used definition with `\deffootnote` and delete there the disturbing `.` like:

```
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \deffootnote{\footnotetextfrommargin}% use distance from above
      {\parindent}% paragraph indent in footnotes
      {\thefootnotemark\space} % <==================================== deleted .
```

Inserting this changed definition after `\begingroup` makes sure it is only valid inside command `\maketitle`.

See the following complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}[%
        Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]
    \newfontfamily\footmarktextfont{CMU Serif}[% for footnote markers in the text
        Numbers = {Lining, Proportional}]

\usepackage{scrextend} % KOMA script for footnote marks hung left of the margin
    \newcommand*\footnotetextfrommargin{0em} % set distance for footnote text from the margin
    \deffootnote{\footnotetextfrommargin}% use distance from above
        {\parindent}% paragraph indent in footnotes
        {\thefootnotemark.\space} % footnote marks followed by a period and space in footnote
    \deffootnotemark{\footmarktextfont\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}} % use footmarktextfont for footnote markers in the text

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% 1. remove all redefinitions about footnotes done by \maketitle
%    and add \titletrue
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \deffootnote{\footnotetextfrommargin}% use distance from above
      {\parindent}% paragraph indent in footnotes
      {\thefootnotemark\space} % <==================================== deleted .
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \titletrue
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
% 2. define a conditional
\newif\iftitle
% 3. redefine \@makefnmark to print nothing when \titletrue
\xpretocmd{\@makefnmark}{\iftitle\else}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@makefnmark}{\fi}{}{}
% 4. ensure \@makefntext has \titlefalse
%    that's justified by the fact that \@makefnmark
%    in \@makefntext is set in a box
\xpretocmd{\@makefntext}{\titlefalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{My paper on footnotes\thanks{\lipsum[4]}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

A\footnote{\lipsum[11]}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

## Update:

To get the asterix on the top of the line (and not at the bottom as you get with `\textasterikscentered`) change the definition of `\@fnsymbol` like this:

```
\renewcommand\@fnsymbol[1]{% <==========================================
  \ifcase #1
    \or  *%
    \or  \textdagger %
    \or  \textddagger %
    \or  \textsection %
    \or  \textparagraph %
    \or  \textbardbl %
    \or  {**}%
    \or  {\textdagger \textdagger}%
    \or  {\textdaggerdbl \textdaggerdbl}%
    \else \@ctrerr 
  \fi %
} % <===================================================================
```

Now test the new following mwe

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{CMU Serif}[%
        Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]
    \newfontfamily\footmarktextfont{CMU Serif}[% for footnote markers in the text
        Numbers = {Lining, Proportional}]

\usepackage{scrextend} % KOMA script for footnote marks hung left of the margin
    \newcommand*\footnotetextfrommargin{0em} % set distance for footnote text from the margin
    \deffootnote{\footnotetextfrommargin}% use distance from above
        {\parindent}% paragraph indent in footnotes
        {\thefootnotemark.\space} % footnote marks followed by a period and space in footnote
    \deffootnotemark{\footmarktextfont\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}} % use footmarktextfont for footnote markers in the text

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@fnsymbol[1]{% <==========================================
  \ifcase #1
    \or  *%
    \or  \textdagger %
    \or  \textddagger %
    \or  \textsection %
    \or  \textparagraph %
    \or  \textbardbl %
    \or  {**}%
    \or  {\textdagger \textdagger}%
    \or  {\textdaggerdbl \textdaggerdbl}%
    \else \@ctrerr 
  \fi %
} % <===================================================================
% 1. remove all redefinitions about footnotes done by \maketitle
%    and add \titletrue
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \deffootnote{\footnotetextfrommargin}% use distance from above
      {\parindent}% paragraph indent in footnotes
      {\thefootnotemark\space} % <====================================== deleted .
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \titletrue
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
% 2. define a conditional
\newif\iftitle
% 3. redefine \@makefnmark to print nothing when \titletrue
\xpretocmd{\@makefnmark}{\iftitle\else}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@makefnmark}{\fi}{}{}
% 4. ensure \@makefntext has \titlefalse
%    that's justified by the fact that \@makefnmark
%    in \@makefntext is set in a box
\xpretocmd{\@makefntext}{\titlefalse}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{My paper on footnotes\thanks{\lipsum[4]}}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

A\footnote{\lipsum[11]}

\end{document}
```

resulting in the following footnotes:

[image: resulting footnotes]

Comment: Nice! Any idea how to get a normal asterisk instead of the lowered/centered one?

Comment: @Sverre see updated answer ...